# Access delegate method in Controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, delegates

I am calling a method which accepts a delegate for write progress messages to. The code snippest below shows what I currently have.

```
public ActionResult CheckProgress(string id)
{
    Recalculator recalculator = new Recalculator(callback);

    ViewBag.PercentDone = recalculator.PercentDone(id);

    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/PartialViews/Progress.cshtml");
}

void callback(string msg)
{
    ViewBag.RecalculationMessage = msg;
}
```

The Recalulcator writes to the `callback` method, and I am trying to store the `msg` in ViewBag. It does not work, however, and I have a feeling I am doing in the complete wrong direction.

How can I access and store the `callback` variables?

Comment: "does not work" doesn't tell us much about what you're observing...

Comment: ViewBag.RecalculationMessage does not contain anything when I call it in my PartialView.

Comment: And have you debugged to find out whether the callback is being executed? Does `PercentDone` definitely call the callback in all situations?

Comment: How does the Recalculator constructor work? And who is supposed to call the callback? Is it the PercentDone method? Please show the code where you call the callback.